# Dynamically Added CheckBox Column is Disabled in GridView

Tags: c#, dynamic, dataset, checkbox

I'm dynamically adding a Boolean column to a DataSet. The DataSet's table is the DataSource for a GridView, which AutoGenerates the columns.

Issue: The checkboxes for this dynamically generated column are all disabled. How can I enable them?

```
ds.Tables["Transactions"].Columns.Add("Retry", typeof(System.Boolean));
ds.Tables["Transactions"].Columns["Retry"].ReadOnly = false;
```

In other words, how can I control how GridView generates the CheckBoxes for a Boolean field? (And why does setting ReadOnly to False have no effect?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add CellContentClick event handler and negate the value that the cell already has. Like:

```
private void dgvRaceDetails_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
            {
                dgvRaceDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value =
                    !(Boolean)dgvRaceDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value;
            }

            if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
            {
                dgvRaceDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value =
                    !(Boolean)dgvRaceDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe they will be automatically disabled until they have a value.

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables["Transactions"].NewRow();
row("Retry") = true;
ds.Tables["Transactions"].Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: Makes no difference. Now they're checked but still disabled.
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Transactions"].Rows)
{
    dr.BeginEdit();
    dr["Retry"] = true;
    dr.EndEdit();
}

Comment: You're right. There's got to be some other code affecting your column.

Answer (score -1):

Set the value of Boolean to true. Its default value is false. I hope this helps.

Comment: How setting `ReadOnly` to `true` will make them not disabled?

Comment: I read it wrong. Adding true/false as value will make them check/unchecked and not enabled/disabled. In my code I was trying to make the checkboxes disabled and mine checkboxes won't do that.

Comment: dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(bool));